# Order of locking in postgres SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

Assuming both table `a` and `b` has a single row, the query

```
 SELECT * FROM a, b FOR UPDATE
```

should get two row-level locks (one on a, one on b). Is there any defined ordering in which the locks are acquired? And is there any way to require the lock from the table b to get acquired lock before the one from a (to avoid deadlocking with other transactions)?

Comment: Deadlocks should generally result in one transaction being aborted arbitrarily.  You normally should not need to worry about this.

Comment: I have other transactions running that acquire the locks in a defined order, so I need to be sure the order these are acquired

Comment: "I need to be sure the order these are acquired" - Why?  The database will break deadlocks for you.  "I have other transactions running that acquire the locks in a defined order" - What's that got to do with anything?

Comment: @Kevin The database breaks deadlocks after a timeout, which kills throughput (the only reason it deadlocks is because of huge amount of simultaneous updates).  And defined order has to do with everything, and its standard deadlock prevention.

Comment: Are you sure you need to lock both sides of the join? If not, just use "FOR UPDATE OF a" to just lock the rows from table a. Not the answer to your question, but it just quite often the case the FOR UPDATE locks more than needed.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I need to lock both sides of the join. (I later go and modify both of them)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any defined ordering in which the locks are acquired?

Not that I know of, for `SELECT *` anyway. Since no lock ordering is documented for this case, you cannot rely on it even if in practice it exists. It might change in a future version.

> And is there any way to require the lock from the table b to get acquired lock before the one from a (to avoid deadlocking with other transactions)?

If you must use `SELECT *` then no. But if you can control the `SELECT`-list, yes. It looks like row locks get acquired in the order the relevant tuple fields appear in the `SELECT` list, so:

```
SELECT a.x, b.x FROM b, a FOR UPDATE;
```

will acquire a lock on the row from `a` then on the row from `b`. At the moment, anyway; I don't think the standard specifies this and don't see any reference to it in the documentation, so *this could change later*.

Personally ... I'd use a `DO` block or separate queries. It might be possible to do it with some subqueries or a CTE, but you'd have to create some form of artificial dependency between them to ensure ordering. Fragile and not worth it.

---

Lets look at what actually happens:

```
regress=> EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) SELECT * FROM a, b FOR UPDATE;
                                  QUERY PLAN                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LockRows  (cost=0.00..129674.00 rows=5760000 width=20)
   Output: a.x, b.x, a.ctid, b.ctid
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..72074.00 rows=5760000 width=20)
         Output: a.x, b.x, a.ctid, b.ctid
         ->  Seq Scan on public.a  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=10)
               Output: a.x, a.ctid
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..46.00 rows=2400 width=10)
               Output: b.x, b.ctid
               ->  Seq Scan on public.b  (cost=0.00..34.00 rows=2400 width=10)
                     Output: b.x, b.ctid
(10 rows)
```

The query gets executed, then the results get fed into a `LockRows` node. What does `LockRows` do? For that, it's time to go source code diving.

[`ExecLockRows` in `src/backend/executor/nodeLockRows.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/nodeLockRows_8c.html#a208adbad38d6d016e878a6dbd129bb46) is the relevant code. There's a lot there, but the gist of it is that it iterates in order over a list of `RowMark`s and acquires each lock in order. The list is set up by [`ExecInitLockRows`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/nodeLockRows_8c.html#aa68a2e00c7ef9b3d6dc2c59bb014bc70), where it copies and filters the list prepared during planning and stored in the `LockRows` node.

I don't have time to trace back in the planner to find the ordering of `LockRows` creation, but IIRC it's basically just the parse order (for `SELECT *`) or the order in which the fields appear in the `SELECT` list (if you didn't use `*`). I recommend not relying on it.